# Where do I put the master_preferences file for a Chromium build on Windows?

Tags: json, chromium

I built Chromium on my machine following their offical documentation. To test out master preferences, I used their example file, but it doesn't work. Where should I be putting the master_preferences file?

I've tried putting it in out/Default, where the .exe is, and AppData/Chromium/UserData.

Comment: Have you managed to bundle ``master_preferences`` file by modifying your mini installer? What are you using ``master_preferences`` file for? Is it for downgrade?

Comment: @Asesh How would I bundle my master_preferences file? I am using it to preinstall extensions and change the default home page (without GPO).

Comment: You will have to modify C++ files to do so. Anyways, that file should be in the same folder where your Chromium executable file is in.

Comment: @Asesh, I've read your answer on how to pre-install an extension with Chrome. It almost works, but when pre-installed it makes a different app ID so the extension gets corrupted. I followed your answer exactly. Any idea  what's wrong?

Comment: You should use your extension's private key file whose extension will be ``.pem``, then it's id shouldn't change.