# How to deploy chromium from source with the master_preferences?

Tags: json, google-chrome, chromium

I have tried following this [Bundle a file in Chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65067558/bundle-a-file-in-chromium) but the file was not present alongside the .exe after the installation, it was added in the version directory. I also read this [Where do I put the master_preferences file for a Chromium build on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55446881/where-do-i-put-the-master-preferences-file-for-a-chromium-build-on-windows) but it wasn't clear about which C++ files I need to edit.

I want to make a mini_installer.exe which creates a master_preferences file in the same folder as the .exe file. I am basically trying to open the welcome page on the first run by the user.

Comment: If you find the answer helpful then please mark it as the answer, so that it will be helpful to others too

Comment: @Asesh I will definitely mark the answer helpful once I get to test your method, I am currently stuck at Branding chromium in MacOS. Can you please check out my other question? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70900380/chromium-branding-in-macos)

Answer (score 0):

The reason I recommended to put `master_preferences` in `VersionDir` in that answer is to make it compatible with incremental updates.

Anyways, in your case you can modify `chrome.release` file and put `master_preferences` in the same directory where `chrome.exe` exists:

```
master_preferences: %(ChromeDir)s\
```

Then build the `mini_installer` again to reflect the changes.